# Saying there is no prompt for input in CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I am completing the Caesar pset 2 assignment for CS50 and when I go to check it, my program keeps telling me that I am not prompting for an input.
I've been working on this for a very long time and still can't seem to figure out the issue.
The program needs an int input so the Caesar cipher can function. I have compared my code to many others doing the same assignment and don't see what I am doing wrong. Please help!

```
        #include <cs50.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <ctype.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        bool only_digits(string s);
        char rotate(char p, int k);

    int main(int argc, string argv[])
    {
    if (argc != 2 || !only_digits(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: caesar./ key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    string p = get_string("plaintext:  ");
    int len = strlen(p);
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        c = rotate(p[i], k);
    }
    printf("ciphertext: , %c\n", c);
}
bool only_digits(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(s[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
char rotate (char p, int k)
{
        char c = 0;
        if (isalpha(p))
            {
                if (isupper(p))
                {
                    c = (p - 'A' + k)%26 + 'A';
                }
                else if (islower(p))
                {
                    c = (p - 'a' + k)%26 + 'a';
                }
                else
                {
                    c = p;
                }
            }
        return c;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. It's hard to work with poorly indented code, especially for beginners.

Comment: `printf("Usage: caesar./ key\n"); return 1;` is fundamentally wrong.  If you want to treat an invocation of the program with an incorrect number of arguments as a valid request for a usage statement, you should print it and `return 0`.  If you want to treat it as an error, you should print an error message (to stderr!) and `return 1`.      A usage statement is not an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this block:

```
 else
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

After program has been run with a valid argument, it will take the else branch and essentially finish. The `return 0;` returns to the command line prompt from the main function, therefore program end.